# How does Weinberg definition of particle states from standard momentum work?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, hilbert-space, quantum-states, elementary-particles

In his first volume, part  2.5, Weinberg define one particle states $Φ_{p,}$ ($p$ is the momentum and $$ another quantum number) in the following way :

1. Choose a Standard momentum $k$
2. Find a Lorentz transformation $ L(p) $ such that $p^\mu = L^\mu _\nu  k^\nu $
3. Define $Φ_{,} : = N(p) (())Φ_{,}$ where $N(p)$ is a normalization factor and  $(())$ the unitary representation of $ L(p) $

However, still according to Weinberg we have $(())Φ_{,} = \sum _{\sigma'} C_{\sigma' \sigma} ((),k)Φ_{,'}  $ with $C_{\sigma' \sigma} ((),k) \in \mathbb{C}$. It means that $Φ_{,}$ is not an eigenvector of $\hat{\sigma}$ (the observable corresponding to the quantum number $\sigma$) with eigenvalue $\sigma $ but a linear combination of eigenvectors. Because of this, I don't understand the definition in point 3. The only way out of this mess would be if $()$ was chosen specifically so that the $\sigma s$ don't mix up.

I know it has been answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199365/weinberg-qft-2-5-5) but I am not convinced. It doesn't make sense to me to be able to simply redefine something that has a physical meaning. It is not a phase.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a remark. If a spectrum is degenerate, then linear combinations of linearly independent eigenvectors all with eigenvalue $\lambda$ are still eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$. I mention this because you seem to immediately assume that $\text{linear combination of eigenvectors} \implies \text{not an eigenvector of original eigenvalue}$.

Comment: Independently, I am confused about what your point is in writing $U(L(p))\Phi_{k, \sigma}$ as as sum. I can similarly write any eigenstate as a linear combination of basis vectors $\lvert 1 \rangle = \sum_i \lvert b_i \rangle$. But this says nothing about the eigenstate.

Comment: @SillyGoose Yes you are right.

Comment: @SillyGoose It Is the how $U(L(p))$ acts on any vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe 3. is literally a definition. That is, while the unitary representation of an *arbitrary* homogenous Lorentz transformation $U(\Lambda)$ acts as:
$$U(\Lambda) \Psi_{\rho, \sigma} = \sum_{\sigma'} C_{\sigma' \sigma}(\Lambda, p)\Psi_{\Lambda p, \sigma'} \tag{2.5.3},$$

Weinberg defines a *particular* (he says that he makes a "standard" choice) sort of homogenous Lorentz transformation $L(p)$ which specifically satisfies 3. as written in your question.

In particular, Weinberg later shows an explicit form for $L(p)$ for mass positive-definite particles on pg. 68, equation 2.5.24. I assume he does the same for massless particles. The following so-called "convenient" form of $L(p)$ as defined by Weinberg is given below:
$$L^i_k(p) = \delta_{ik}+(\gamma^2-1)\hat{p}_i\hat{p}_k, \tag{2.5.24}$$

which is certainly a more particular form than that of (2.5.3).

Comment: So he assumes the existence of $L(p)$ such that $ k \rightarrow p$ which also leaves the $\sigma$ invariant ?

Comment: Correct. @Samael